# AWS: Too many connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-rds

I have an `RDS instance` hosting a mySQL database. Instance size is **db.t2.micro**

[image]

I also have an `ExpressJS` backend connecting to the mySQL `RDS instance` via a connection pool:

[image]

Additionally i have a mobile app, the client, feeding off the `ExpressJS` API.

The issue i'm facing is, either via the mobile app or via Postman, there are times where i get a '**Too many connections**' error and therefore several requests fail:

[image]

On the `RDS instance`. On current activity i sometimes get 65 connections, showing it's reaching the limit. What i need clarity on is:

1. When 200 mobile app instances connect to the API, to the `RDS instance`, does it register as 200 connections or 1 connection from `ExpressJS`?
2. Is it normal to be reaching the RDS instance 65 connection limit?
3. Is this just a matter of me using **db.t2.micro** instance size which is not recommended for prod? Will upgrading the instance size resolve this issue?
4. Is there something i'm doing wrong with my requests?

Thank you and your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Default RDS connection limit is based on instance size but can be changed. It looks like you're explicitly setting the pool size limit to 100 in your screenshot.

Comment: Hi @jordanm, yes, i am, after having noted the rds instance seems to limit to about less than 100 connections, i thought a pool connection limit of 100 wasn't the issue, without it, the default is 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your app creates a connection pool of 100, that's the number of database connections it will try to open. It must be lower than your MySQL connection limit.

Typically connection pools open *all* the connections for the pool, so they are ready when a client calls the http API. The connections might normally be running no SQL queries, if there are not many clients using the API at a given moment. The database connections are nevertheless connected.

Sort of like when you `ssh` to a remote linux server but you just sit there at a shell prompt for a while before running any command. You're still connected.

You asked if a `db.t2.micro` instance was not recommended for production. Yes, I would agree with that. It's tempting to use the smallest instance possible to save money, but a `db.t2.micro` is too small for anything but light testing, in my opinion.

In fact, I would not use *any* `t2` instance for production, regardless of size. The `t2` type uses "burstable" performance. This means it can provide only brief periods of good performance. Once the instance depletes its performance credits, they recharge slowly, and while they recharge, the performance of that instance is very low. This is okay for testing, but not for production, if you expect to provide consistent performance at any time.

Comment: Agreed, t2 is NOT meant for any PRODUCTION instance.